# How should I design subcategory login site?

Tags: customization, multisite

I am trying to design a specific type of site and would like someone to point me in the right direction.

- main home page with list of public subsites (categories i think). Also a form to become a admin of new category/subsite
- Super admin accepts new pending category admins
- category admins accepts new pending users to allow them to view his posts
- nice front end for cat-admin for creating new posts (not so wordpressy)
- Users could log in from the home page and then redirect to category he registered for but not other categories

So i have looked into wordpress multi-site but it says there in the [documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/before-you-create-a-network/)

> if all you want is for different groups of users to have access to different information, then you can probably achieve what you want in a single site by using a plugin to switch capabilities, menus, and link URLs.

I have tried nearly a dozen plugins but they dont seem to have the functionality i want

Comment: Sounds like some sort of membership system, note that plugin recommendations are off topic here, can you narrow this down to a specific thing? Right now it's rather open ended, a discussion on a forum might be better

Comment: @TomJNowell i tried posting on wordpress.org forum but i can't figure out exactly where and how to post question. could you show me or post it for me?

Comment: I don't have the answer to that, somebody on the .org forums might be able to better help